# Can I set customised title bar for a master detail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to have an 
-Image button 
-logo
-text view
How to set the title bar with these constraints?

Comment: You can add a image to help to explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add them by Toolbar Items in XAML

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
          <ToolbarItem Icon="logo.png" Text="Sample" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unless you create your own custom toolbar from scratch using custom renderers.